# It is sufficient to know the discrete spectrum in a dense to know it in all the Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $A$ be a dense set in a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$. Let $\sigma_{disc}$ be discrete spectrum (*the set of all isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity*) of an operator $B$. 
Let $\sigma_{disc}^A$ be the set of all isolated eigenvalues of finite multiplicity associated with vector  of the set $A$.

Is this relation true $\sigma_{disc}^A=\sigma_{disc}$?

In another words it is sufficient to know the discrete spectrum in a dense to know it in all the Hilbert space?

Answer (score 1):

Of course not.  $A$ might not contain any eigenvectors at all.

Comment: i will modify my question